# std::cout seems to be printing out an extra "|" when called initially

Tags: c++11

I am working on a portion of my code that is suppose to output the error message correctly.

Please see below screenshot, I am using on bash

./myProgram < input3a.in | diff -a -y output3a.out -

Left hand side is what I want to get to.

[image]

For some reason an extra "|" is printed before the char array 'line' is printed. I suspected that maybe the char array 'line' is not null terminated. but it is initialize by cin.getline(); which should null terminate the char array.

Here i try to print the 'line' array in my main procedure, and it left the | sign on the line before it. [image]

my question is. why does std::cout display this behaviour?

Thanks

EDIT,

Below is my code in question. Thanks for taking a look again.

```
#include "char_stack.h"
#include <iostream>


void printErrorLine(int errorSpot, int c_count, char line[]){
    //Print the first line of error message char by char, at the
    //same time replace char with \t or space
    for(int x = 0; x <= errorSpot; x++){
        std::cout << line[x];

        if(line[x] != '\t'){
            line[x] = ' ';  
        }
    }   
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //Print out the second line, if the first line does not have a 
    //errorSpot, then dont print it
    if(errorSpot != c_count){
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}


char findCounterPart(char bracket){
    //pass.
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char line[250];     // 250 because spec sheet detailed max 250 char per line.
    char c;
    int l_count = 0;    // number of lines already read
    int c_count;        // character count in a line
    char_stack S;

    bool isError;

    while(!std::cin.peek() == std::cin.eof()){
        std::cin.getline(line, 250);
        c_count = std::cin.gcount();
        l_count +=1;
        //std::cout<< c_count << std::endl << std::endl;
        //loop through the line
        for(int x = 0; x < c_count; x++){
            c = line[x];
            //std::cout << c << " stack size is " << S.size() << std::endl;

            if (c == '(' || 
                c == '{' || 
                c == '['){
                S.push(c);  
            }

            else if(c == ')' ||
                    c == '}' ||
                    c == ']'){

                if(S.empty()){
                    std::cout << "Error on line " << l_count << ": Too many " << c << std::endl;
                    isError = true;
                }
                else{
                    char l = S.pop();
                    if(l != findCounterPart(c)){
                        std::cout << "Error on line " << l_count << ": Read " << c <<
                        ", expected " << findCounterPart(l) << std::endl;
                        isError = true;
                    }
                }
            }   

            if (isError){
                printErrorLine(x, c_count ,line);
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }

    if (!S.empty()){
        c = S.pop();
        std::cout << "Error on line " << l_count << ": Too many " << c << std::endl;
        printErrorLine(c_count, c_count , line);
    }
    else{
        std::cout <<"No Errors Found" << std::endl;     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell since I can't see your code... :)

Comment: If you do not understand that it is necessary to examine the code, in order to determine the answer for this kind of a question, then maybe C++ is not going to work out for you.

Comment: Did it occur to you to look at the two files directly?

Comment: @JefréN  I have included the codes, I'd love your input. thanks for looking again.

Answer (score 0):

Learning to be a software engineer is about breaking problems down into manageable chunks, and here we have a couple of doosies. Lets rephrase your question slightly:

> I am getting unexpected characters displayed when `diff` the output of my program against a file containing output of a previous run. Currently I think this is because of some weird behavior of std::cout.

Well, that might be a reasonable assumption, we can't see your code so we can't know if you're doing anything peculiar.

But it would have to be: std::cout is used, well, all over the place. It just doesn't have this behavior unless your code is deliberately writing a `|` somewhere.

There are a number of steps we could take to resolve this:

1. Run the program a 3rd time in the debugger and step through until you have some ideas where the '|' is appearing,
2. Run the program a 3rd time to the console and observe the output,
3. View the output using a command like `cat`, `less` or `more`, instead of `diff`

3 is perhaps the most sensible place to start, since the file is already right there and after that #2 will give us a mk1eyeball check.

What we find is: the `|` does not appear in the file or the output. It's not coming from your program.

Lets create a couple of .txt files and diff them:

```
osmith@WOTSIT MINGW64 ~
$     echo -e 'First line\nSecond line' >test1.txt
osmith@WOTSIT MINGW64 ~
$     echo -e 'First line\nFile two line 2' >test2.txt
osmith@WOTSIT MINGW64 ~
$     diff -a -y test1.txt test2.txt
First line                                                      First line
Second line                                                   | File two line 2
```

When using the `-y` switch, between the two columns of output, `diff` has a line of special characters to indicate lines that changed, were inserted or deleted.

Comment: thanks for your comments, and the different output commands, I am new to bash (and c++ as you can tell) . So the | is from the -y flag, and not the cause of why the outputs are different. I am going to try the bash commands as you have recommended.  In the mean time, I have updated my question with codes. I would love for you to take a glance. Thanks again.

Comment: when i use 'less myOutput.txt' i can see that there is a ^@ null output at end of my file. I believe this is causing the discrepancy.